# MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE not working.

Tags: php, mysql

When I run the importdata.php to import data.  Nothing happen and no error message.  The importdata.php and mydata.csv file located in the same folder.  Here is my code.  Thanks for helping to find what is wrong.

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE 'mydata.csv' INTO TABLE tbl_test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Please try to execute this directly agains mysql and let us know the result. "LOAD DATA INFILE 'mydata.csv' INTO TABLE tbl_test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES";

Comment: not exactly error trapping the final query are ya. Just plod on.

Comment: normally one would path to the file by the way. Where is PHP to find it?

Answer (score 1):

You've instructed MySql (not PHP) to look for a file called "mydata.csv" and it can't find it because you have stored it in Apache's working directory, rather than MySql's.

Is MySql on the same server as Apache?  If so, just give it the full path to the file.  Eg: LOAD DATA INFILE '\var\htdocs\myapp\mydata.csv'.

If MySql is on a different server, you're outta luck unless you can upload the file to the MySql server.